# How I can implement two caching strategy in UIL

Tags: java, android, caching, universal-image-loader

How I can impement two cahing strategy in one application. Eg images from one app section should be cashing in one folder and have max memory/time limit etc. And images from another section should be have another folder etc. These strategies should not depend on each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ImageLoader is singleton but it provides protected constructor so you can extend `ImageLoader` and create the 2nd singleton:

```
public class ImageLoader2 extends ImageLoader {

    private volatile static ImageLoader instance;

    /** Returns singleton class instance */
    public static ImageLoader getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            synchronized (ImageLoader2.class) {
                if (instance == null) {
                    instance = new ImageLoader2();
                }
            }
        }
        return instance;
    }
}
```

and use it with other configuration.